# jar dependency in maven pom.xml to avoid from specific repository?

Tags: maven, pom.xml

Suppose I have a jar dependency added in maven pom.xml and I am referring two repositories .If that jar is available from both Repos ,how can I avoid loading from second repo and just use from first Repository?

Comment: If you have two different artifacts with the exact same coordinate on 2 different repo, you'll in a world of pain. Why would you ever want to have that?

Comment: This is a broken situation to be in. There should not be two artifacts with the same name in two repos that are different. You would expect to see something like that only if somebody is doing something malicious. You can use an artifact repository like Nexus to detect and resolve this situation. Or pick one of the two artifacts and upload it under a unique name, then refer to that unique name.